# How do I know the version of a transitive dependency that a Spring Boot starter dependency brings into my project?

Tags: spring-boot

For example, how do I find out the version of Hibernate that the Spring Boot `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` starter dependency is bringing into my project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list of dependencies is available in [the Appendix F. of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) and in the **pom.xml** of the **spring-boot-dependencies** artifact, which you should be able to find on your classpath.

You can also go the public repository of Spring Boot and [see the pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.4.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L46) for every released version in a separate branch.

Comment: I couldn't find the pom.xml in my target folder/war, but I did find the version in the documentation, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

When using maven, use the below command to print dependency tree

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

When using gradle:

```
gradlew dependencies
```

> dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'my-project'.
>
> dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'my-project'.

Also, an IDE shows this information in some window. For example, IntelliJ shows all project dependencies in the project window under 'External Libraries' and in the maven window.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement Yuva's answer, if you are looking for hibernate's version, you may run

`gradle dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate --configuration compile`

or

```
gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate --configuration compileClasspath
```

or if your project is structured as a [multi-project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), under project root run

`gradle submodule:dependencyInsight --dependency hibernate --configuration compile`

The command gives result for `what depends on hibernate in this project` whereas `gradle dependencies` gives result for `what dependencies this project have`

Answer (score 0):

can also be found here:

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/<version>/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions
```

where version is spring-boot-starter-parent version. e.g.

```
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.17.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions
```

Answer (score 0):

we can get the version of Spring & SpringBoot from respective class SpringBootVersion & SpringVersion
SpringBootVersion.getVersion()
SpringVersion.getVersion()